# Create tallies of levels by column in R?

Tags: r

I want to get a count of the alleles within a matrices with levels- "A","T","C","G". I want this to be done column-wise and printed into a new dataset. How can I do this in R? I've attached a picture of the dataset below:

[image: Dataset]

Comment: Maybe: `apply(m, 2, table)` ?

Comment: We tried that but each column has different levels- so V30 has A and C and V40 has C and G etc.

Comment: What should your expected output look like? @GKi solution above seems to work for me.

Comment: Perhaps  you need `apply(m, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c("A", "C", "T", "G"))))`

Comment: Expected output is as per Allan Cameron's comment! @GKi solution does work but not in a genetic context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data are not reproducible, let's make a compatible data set:

```r
set.seed(69)

m <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), 100, TRUE), nrow = 10))

m
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#> 1   G  C  C  G  C  A  T  A  T   A
#> 2   A  A  A  C  C  A  A  T  G   C
#> 3   T  T  T  T  G  C  C  G  G   G
#> 4   C  C  G  G  G  A  A  A  G   A
#> 5   G  C  A  A  G  C  T  A  C   T
#> 6   G  T  T  T  A  A  A  C  C   A
#> 7   A  G  T  G  A  A  A  A  C   A
#> 8   T  C  A  A  G  A  A  T  A   T
#> 9   T  T  C  T  T  T  C  A  T   G
#> 10  T  C  C  T  T  T  G  G  C   A
```

We can get the answer like this:

```
t(apply(m, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c("A", "C", "T", "G")))))
#>     A C T G
#> V1  2 1 4 3
#> V2  1 5 3 1
#> V3  3 3 3 1
#> V4  2 1 4 3
#> V5  2 2 2 4
#> V6  6 2 2 0
#> V7  5 2 2 1
#> V8  5 1 2 2
#> V9  1 4 2 3
#> V10 5 1 2 2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could also do this by `unlist`ing the dataset and calling `table` once

```
table(c(col(m)), unlist(m))
```

-output

```
#     A C G T
#  1  2 1 3 4
#  2  1 5 1 3
#  3  3 3 1 3
#  4  2 1 3 4
#  5  2 2 4 2
#  6  6 2 0 2
#  7  5 2 1 2
#  8  5 1 2 2
#  9  1 4 3 2
#  10 5 1 2 2
```

#### data

```
set.seed(69)
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), 100, TRUE), nrow = 10))
```